# how handle message from API - flutter

Tags: api, flutter, dart

I'm newbie in flutter .I'm workin on API requests . MY API response from server like this  :

```
{
    "code": 1,
    "message": "User name updated with success !",
    "data": [],
    "error": [],
    "status": 200
}
```

I would like to  display the message content in snackbar to user .

my code :

```
  Future<String> editUserProfile(
      String name, String email, String adress) async {
    SharedPreferences localStorage = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    String token = localStorage.getString('access_token');
    await checkInternet();
    Map<String, String> headers = {
      'Content-type': 'application/json',
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Authorization': 'Bearer $token'
    };
    Map<String, dynamic> body = {
      'name': name,
      'email': email,
      'adress': adress,
    };
  
    var response = await http.post(Uri.parse(ApiUtil.MODIFY_USER_PROFILE),
        headers: headers, body: jsonEncode(body));
    print(response.statusCode);
    print(response);
    inspect(response);

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      if (response.body.isNotEmpty) {
        body = jsonDecode(response.body);
      }
      var data = body['message'];
      return data;
    } else {
      throw Exception('Failed to modify name');
    }
  }


 void editUserProfile() async {
    setState(() {});

    String name = _nameController.text;
    String email = _emailController.text;
    String adress = _adressController.text;

    userApi.editUserProfile(name, email, adress).then((data) {
      if (data != null) {
        Navigator.pop(context);

     
      }
   
    }).catchError((error) {
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context)
          .showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text(error.toString())));
    });
    setState(() {});
  }
```

How i can showing the message getting from backend dynamically to user in snackBar ?

for more information :

update 1  : the input text code :

```
Row(
   mainAxisAlignment:MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
   children: [
     Text(
       'Adresse :',
       style: TextStyle(
         color: Color( 0xFF4053FCF),
         fontSize: 16,
         fontWeight:FontWeight.w600),
       ),
     IconButton(
       icon: Icon(CommunityMaterialIcons.pencil,
          color: Colors.grey,
       ),
       onPressed: () {
         adresseNode.requestFocus();
         setState(() {
            enableadress = true;
         });
       })
    ],
 ),
 TextFormField(
   enabled: enableadress,
   controller:_adressController,
   focusNode: adresseNode,
   enableInteractiveSelection: false,
   keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
   decoration: InputDecoration(
     hintText: "${snapshot.data.adress}",
     hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey,fontSize:14.0)),
 ),
```

Comment: You seem to have everything in place. What seems to be the issue

Comment: in my case i can't get the message : User name updated with success !

Comment: it appear in the console but no appear in the screen

Comment: what is the value of `data`  when you are checking `data != null` ?

Comment: data :User name updated with success !

Comment: I added an answer, did you try it like that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are already returning the data correctly in your Future, all you need to do is just use that to show a SnackBar.

```
if (data != null) {
  Navigator.pop(context);

  // Add this line
  ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text(data)));
}
```

Comment: but i have other problem . i want to stay at the same screen after getting data from api.  . i think it's a problem about setState(() {}. how i can reolve it ?

Comment: Remove the `Navigator.pop(context);` line. What it does is, it removes the current page so you go back to previous page

Comment: you are great man . it works fine . i have other small problem. after getting data from api ... the input text still active. i want the input text back disable after getting data .

Comment: disable as in non editable or clear the text within the input ?

Comment: i updated my code . you can check the input text code .

Comment: it's for adress input . i want to  back disable before i make decision to rewrite next time

Comment: yes, you can add `setState(() { enableadress = false; })` above the new `Snackbar` code I have given you

Comment: in fact i have 3 input : adress name and email . i add 3 setState(() { enableadress = false; }) ??

Comment: Inside the single `setState`, add all code line by line